# Constant and Overloaded Constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a class that is primarily used to "structuralized" buffer. One client generally use to write and the other used to read. For the writing, there are default values that the class would set, but for read, it should leave it alone.

```
class Formatter
{
public:
  //! Used by writer
  Formatter( unsigned char* Buffer ) :
    m_Buffer( Buffer )
  {
      Buffer[ 0 ] = 1; //say this is the format
  }

  //! Used by reader
  Formatter( const unsigned char* Buffer ) :
    m_Buffer( Buffer )
  {

  }

  //...Other methods returns pointer to structure

private:
  unsigned char* m_Buffer;
};
```

The problem here is that it is easy for a reader to make the mistake by passing in a non-const buffer.

```
//..assume pBuffer is non-const
//We really want to read
const Formatter myFormatter( pBuffer );
//We really want const Formatter myFormatter( const_cast<const unsigned char*>(pBuffer) );
```

I can't really think if a nice way to prevent user from making this mistake, without having the user being explicit.

Anyone know of a nice trick?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not create two different classes?

Comment: why not creating to different methods, read and write, each getting different level of const-ness? the the constructor is default - no arguments.

Comment: Those are the solutions I have in mind. Was just wondering if there was some better way.
It would be nice to be able to have "mutable const" constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct writer_access {};
Formatter( writer_access, unsigned char* Buffer ) :
```

here we tag the constructor with different semantics with a tag.  Accidental use should be nearly impossible.  You call it by passing `(writer_access{}, pbuff)`

Comment: This is actually a neat method. One problem I still see, if someone trying to write and forget to have the "writer_access", the constructor for reading is called, the one with the supposedly const unsigned char*. Compiler won't catch this, so we supposedly have the reversed effect.

Comment: I guess I can take the read constructor with a similar struct reader_access {}; Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Two tricks come to my mind:

1. Make `Formatter` abstract and provide subclasses of it, one for reading, one for writing:

   ```
   class ReadFormatter : public Formatter {
     public:
       ReadFormatter(const unsigned char*);
   };

   class WriteFormatter : public Formatter {
     public:
       WriteFormatter(unsigned char*);
   };
   ```
2. Create two static member functions for the two tasks:

   ```
   static Formatter ReadFormatter(…) { … }
   static Formatter WriteFormatter(…) { … }
   ```

IMO subclassing would be the better way.

Comment: By the way, the static member functions way is commonly known as the "named constructor idiom".

Comment: Good stuff. You think subclassing would be the better way because of performance?

Comment: Definitely not because of performance. Because it's clearer and more intuitive. Objects are normally created by calling constructors, not by calling static member functions. The performance difference is negligible, but  the second way _might_ be more performant in some situations because it avoids polymorphism.